# SetGID on newly created directories in ProFTPd 1.3.4

Tags: file-permissions, ftp

I discovered a change in some recent version of ProFTPd - I used `Umask 0007` to remove permissions to "others" but it kept my SetGID directory flag - which is what I wanted.

In recent version (1.3.4) my permission system stopped to work. I am unable to convince ProFTPd to set SetGID flag on newly created directories.

In documentation they say "base-mode" for creating directories is 0777 and `UMask` allows only to remove permissions.

How to make it set SetGID bit on new directories, that is permissions 2770?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, answering my own question: I did not find the cause of this, but when I enabled `mod_vroot` plugin and added `VRootEngine on`, everything went back to normal.